# AWS route 53 database hostname best practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, amazon-route53, hostname

So I have 3 components all connecting to same db. Should I use:

```
comp1.domain.io  
comp1db.domain.io

comp2.domain.io  
comp2db.domain.io

comp3.domain.io  
comp3db.domain.io
```

Or:

```
comp1.domain.io  
comp2.domain.io  
comp3.domain.io  
db.domain.io
```

**EDIT:** I am wondering if the ease of API accessible Route 53 hostnames makes it more beneficial to create hostnames for the db server per application. This means if I need to transfer the DB of a particular application off to a different server, I just have to modify the hostname.

Traditionally it's usually `db.domain.io`, but that's because DNS entries is just not easily accessible and editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has very little to do with Amazon Web Services but is connected to an overall server infrastructure layout. With that in mind I would recommend you structure your servers like this:

```
comp1.domain.io  
comp2.domain.io  
comp3.domain.io  
db.domain.io
```

While you say:

> So I have 3 components all connecting to same db.

It’s not clear if you mean DB host or database itself. If for some reason each of the hosts needed their own DB, you could just come up with a database naming scheme such as:

```
comp1_db
comp2_db
comp3_db
```

And all of those DBs could be hosted at `db.domain.io`.

**EDIT:** This is in response to the original poster’s edit.  If you have to transfer the DB, the process is never seamless & will take effort.  A hostname change for something like this is fairly radical & is out of your control. Amazon Route 53 is one thing, but DNS behavior outside of the Amazon hosting ecosystem is another. It’s better for you in the long run to just use a common hostname but different DBs & perhaps related credentials.

Comment: Apology, please see edit.

Comment: @SleeperSmith I saw you edit & I think you are overthinking the issue. See my edit in response.